# Styling doesn't work after updating xamarin forrms

Tags: android, ios, button, xamarin.forms, telerik

My buttons on my app are supposed to be round at the edges making the button like ean oval shape. After updating my xamairin forms and adding a few dlls, the button appearance is always square-ish even though I have set the border radius of the button on the content page itself. Seems like this is the only thing wrong with the styling as the background color set in the app.xaml page still works.

I have these warning messages:

```
                        Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Mono.Android". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. CompNam.MobileApp           
Warning     The referenced component 'Mono.Android' could not be found. CompNam.MobileApp           
Warning     The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll (vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.    CompNam.MobileApp.Android   C:\Users\User\Short\CompNamPortalApp\CompNam.MobileApp\CompNam.MobileApp.Android\CompNam.MobileApp.Android.csproj       
Warning     The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for FormsViewGroup.dll (vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.    CompNam.MobileApp.Android   C:\Users\User\Short\CompNamPortalApp\CompNam.MobileApp\CompNam.MobileApp.Android\CompNam.MobileApp.Android.csproj       
Warning     The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll (vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.    CompNam.MobileApp.Android   C:\Users\User\Short\CompNamPortalApp\CompNam.MobileApp\CompNam.MobileApp.Android\CompNam.MobileApp.Android.csproj       
Warning     The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.dll (vv8.0) is greater than the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project (v7.1). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for your project.   CompNam.MobileApp.Android   C:\Users\User\Short\CompNamPortalApp\CompNam.MobileApp\CompNam.MobileApp.Android\CompNam.MobileApp.Android.csproj
```

Are any of these messages affecting the appearance of the button?

Comment: Try change your Android target version from Android 7.1 to Android 8.0.

Comment: I am trying to target lower versions of Android. Is there any other option other than changing the target framework? I have also tried changing to 8.0 but a bunch of other warnings appeared.

Comment: I think we'd likely need to see some code to help you pinpoint the problem.